# How to get a list of concatenated text nodes

Tags: xpath

My purpose is to request on a xml structure, using only one XPath evaluation, in order to get a list of strings containing the concatenation of text3 and text5 for each "my_class" div.

The structure example is given below:

```
 <div>   
     <div>
         <div class="my_class">
             <div class="my_class_1"></div>
             <div class="my_class_2">text2</div>
             <div class="my_class_3">
                 text3
                 <div class="my_class_4">text4</div>
                 <div class="my_class_5">text5</div>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="my_class_6"></div>   
     </div>   
     <div>
         <div class="my_class">
             <div class="my_class_1"></div>
             <div class="my_class_2">text12</div>
             <div class="my_class_3">
                 text13
                 <div class="my_class_4">text14</div>
                 <div class="my_class_5">text15</div>
             </div>
         </div>   
     </div>  
 </div>
```

This means I want to get this list of results:
    - in index 0 => text3 text5
    - in index 1 => text13 text15

I currently can only get the my_class nodes, but with the text12 that I want to exclude ; or a list of each string, not concatened.

How I could proceed ?

Thanks in advance for helping.

EDIT : I remove text4 and text14 from my search to be exact in my example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: Now the question has changed...

**XPath 1.0**: There is no such thing as *"list of strings"* data type. You can use this expression to select all the container elements of the text nodes you want:

```
/div/div/div[@class='my_class']/div[@class='my_class_3']
```

And then get <del>with the proper DOM method of your host language the **string value** of every of those selected elements (the concatenation of all descendant text nodes)</del> the descendat text nodes you want and concatenate their string value with the proper relative XPath or DOM method:

```
text()[1]|div[@class='my_class_5']
```

**XPath 2.0**: There is a sequence data type.

```
/div/div/div[@class='my_class']
           /div[@class='my_class_3']
              /concat(text()[1],div[@class='my_class_5'])
```

Comment: Does it mean it is impossible to get several text contents in sibling nodes, except one of its, in only one response ?

Comment: @carpediem: XPath selects nodes. You can select all those text nodes you want, but your result will be a node set (not "concatenation" relationship between them). My path selects **every container** of the text nodes you want, not just one.

Comment: @Alejandro & @Paul: Ok. After a couple of tests, this works. I already tried this function but my error was finally about how to retreive the results set. I had to change casts in this case. Thank you all for helping

Comment: @Alejandro: Thank you. It's very nice to be helped with accuracy so  quickly :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just use:

```
//my_class/my_class_3
```

And then get the .innerText from that? There might be a bit of spacing cleanup to do but it should contain all the inside text (including that from the class 4 and 5) but without the tags.

---

Edit: After clairification

```
concat(/div/div/div[@class=my_class]/div[@class=my_class_3]/text(), ' ', /div/div/div[@class=my_class]/div[@class=my_class_5]/text())
```

That might work

Comment: yes. you are absolutely right. I tried some time to construct my example and I realize that it doesn't match exactly my problem. In fact, my real problem is out to get this tag's content (my_class3) without text4 and text14 for instance. I'm going to modify it to be exact.